# How to empty the cell content if multiple data matches within Range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet where I want to clear cell data if multiple matches are found within a range.

**Example image**

[image]

If matches are found like *SUP* or *AL* then clear the content and color the cell corresponding to the match found (e.g SUP - yellow, AL - Red). I have used Below code it is not working.

```
Dim l As Long, lRow As Long
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For l = 1 To lRow
    For Each c In Range("A:AE")
    If c.Value = "SUP" Then
    c.Value = ""
    End If
    Next l
End With
```

Comment: I think this question is answered? It looks like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291997/change-the-cell-property-to-no-fille-if-match-is-found-vbaexcel/56292298#56292298

Answer (score 0):

This one should work

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim c As Range, arr As Range

Set arr = Range("A7:AE7")

For Each c In arr
    If InStr(1, c, "SUP") Or InStr(1, c, "AL") Then
       c.Clear
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: your code works but it only deletes data of only single row (first row only)  .... ? How to do for loop until the end row to find match and clear that data

Comment: Change `Range("A7:AE7")` to the range you require. For example `Range("A7:AE999")`

Comment: I want to tell you like above image if you look their is Range A:AE and Used Row is from Range 1 to 8 only this Range of Rows it should search the SUP Between A:AE and Clear content

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Thisworbook.Worksheets '// loop on all worksheet //
  With sh

    Set r = .Range("A1:AE7") '// adjust to your actual range //
    For Each c In r
      With c
        Select Case UCase(.Value2) '// non case sensitive search //
        Case "SUP": .ClearContents: .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Case "AL": .ClearContents: .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End Select
      End With
    Next

  End With
Next
```

Edit1: Added looping through all worksheets and the non-case sensitive search. Not tested, but should give you idea on how to do it.

Comment: Your Code works but has one issue when I give a range only how many used rows are there that many rows should search and delete the data in that cells ... your code goes infinite loop kindly change and give me the code

Comment: I want to tell you like above image if you look their is Range A:AE and Used Row is from Range 1 to 8 only this Range of Rows it should search the SUP Between A:AE and Clear content

Comment: @pognunusta Yes, as commented, adjust the search range to suit.

Comment: L42 => code works perfectly => will you be able to add in the code it should even detect the match word in caps or small letters like => SUP , sup,Sup,SuP,sUP => no matter it is caps or small should be able to detect it and erase it => even add array of sheets like [sheet1,sheet2,sheet3] so that when button is pressed all the matching data should be cleared from all the sheets

Comment: can you add array of sheets

Comment: @pognunusta Adjusted it. Moving forward, make sure to clearly state your issue and with specific problem on your question and not just give requirements like someone from the community will code for you. Otherwise, your question will most likely be ignored and closed.