# Change the Cell property to No fill if Match is Found |VBA|Excel|

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete the Content of the Cell within Row Range 1:6 and Column Range A:AE if match is Found "SUP" and "AL"

Range is Colored in yellow for the reference please have a look at the below image

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: What is "Not working"? Gives an error? Does nothing? Not what you expected?

Comment: gets error at for loop For l .....

Comment: Hey, this is not how it works. You've asked this question for a 3rd time today. Be more specific with your description and problem encountered with your code instead of asking the same question over and over.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289632/how-to-empty-the-cell-content-if-multiple-data-matches-within-range/56289906?noredirect=1#comment99195868_56289906

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little bit confused but would this be what you meant?

```
Sub FindReplaceAll()

Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior.Pattern = xlNone

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:AE6")
    .Cells.Replace what:=UCase("SUP"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=True
    .Cells.Replace what:=UCase("SUP"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=False
    .Cells.Replace what:=UCase("AL"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=True
    .Cells.Replace what:=UCase("AL"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=False
End With

End Sub
```

If need be you can apply `LookAt:=xlPart` or `LookAt:=xlWhole` too.

Comment: it works according to my need only one thing change I need how do I set the cell property to no fill color in the above code which you have shared .... like if match is found then data should be cleared and even the colored cell should be  with no color I am using this code but entire range is no fill Range("A:AF").Interior.ColorIndex = 0 only matched content should be no fill

Comment: @pognunusta, Update your initial question please as this was no requirement.

Comment: @pognunusta, have a look at updated answer as well.

Comment: how do I consider case sensitive Even if it Caps or Small Letter data should be clear like AL or al or Al , SUP , sup , Sup even if its in small letters or big letters or any other way it should identify and clear the cells

Comment: => Awsome => would you be able to add an array to your code that your code takes  multiple sheets name instead of only one sheet like this => arr[sheet1,sheet2,sheet3] instead of ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:AE6")  because I want to repeat the same clearing  match word in all sheet at once

Comment: @pognunusta, you will have to loop through the worksheets. Only if you sure there are no matches to `SUP` or `AL` outside your searchrange, you could safely apply this to the entire workbook by removing `With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:AE6")` and removing `End With`

Comment: how do I pass only required sheets name only not every sheet => are you able to re update the above code according to this requirement

Comment: @pognunusta, sounds like a new question to me (refering to this question). You can't keep adding to a question, also you should really give it a try yourself, it's the best way to learn some code by just doing it, also this is no free coding website. Thank you